# Configuring Apache solr 4.5.1 with Godaddy Shared hosting and VPS server

Tags: php, apache, solr, drupal-7

I have installed Apache Solr on a VPS server and my Drupal 7 application currently running in a Godaddy shared hosting. When I tested the connection with my local machine which is running under XAMPP (Windows environment), the connection are creating without any issue. However when I put the same configuration on my Godaddy shared hosting it saying

> "Your site was unable to connect the Apache Solr server".

[image: Your site was unable to connect the Apache Solr server.]

Is there any issue with Godaddy shared hosting to connect with Apache Solr? Or, something special is required to connect with Solr which is present in local XAMPP but not in shared Godaddy server? Your help is highly appropriated.

Comment: Check with GoDaddy, they might not allow connections on other ports than 80 and 443 (default http and https ports).

Comment: Correct! I have changed the solar port to 80 and it worked.

Comment: Great, I make the comment into an answer, please approve :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, GoDaddy probably does not allow external connections on other ports than 80 or 443.